# Python script to query the S3 CloudFront access logs from AWS Athena and import the select query to an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am planning to run this script on Lambda function on a daily basis and get the list of IP addresses and find any suspicious IP address and add to the WAF block rule. But my problem here is in the script I might need to manually change the Table name as it cant overwrite with the same existing table on AWS Athena and need to update the S3 bucket_input for the current day. So is there a way to automate this as well

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3

#Function for executing athena queries
def run_query(query, database, s3_output):
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': s3_accesslog1
            },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': s3_output,
            }
        )
    print('Execution ID: ' + response['QueryExecutionId'])
    return response
    
#Athena configuration
s3_input = 's3://smathena/athenatest/'
s3_ouput = 's3://python-demo/Test-Athena/'
database = 's3_accesslog1'
table = 'Test_output'

#Athena database and table definition
create_database = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s;" % (database)
create_table = \
  """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s.%s (
  `Date` DATE,
   Time STRING,
   Location STRING,
   SCBytes BIGINT,
   RequestIP STRING,
   Method STRING,
   Host STRING,
   Uri STRING,
   Status INT,
   Referrer STRING,
   UserAgent STRING,
   UriQS STRING,
   Cookie STRING,
   ResultType STRING,
   RequestId STRING,
   HostHeader STRING,
   Protocol STRING,
   CSBytes BIGINT,
   TimeTaken FLOAT,
   XForwardFor STRING,
   SSLProtocol STRING,
   SSLCipher STRING,
   ResponseResultType STRING,
   CSProtocolVersion STRING,
   FleStatus STRING,
   FleEncryptedFields INT,
   CPort INT,
   TimeToFirstByte FLOAT,
   XEdgeDetailedResult STRING,
   ScContent STRING,
   ScContentLen BIGINT,
   ScRangeStart BIGINT,
   ScRangeEnd BIGINT
   )
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
   LOCATION '%s'
   TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count' = '2');""" % ( database, table, s3_input )

#Query definitions
query_1 = "SELECT requestip, count(*) FROM %s.%s group by requestip order by count(*) desc" % (database, table)
query_2 = "SELECT * FROM %s.%s where useragent = googlebot" % (database, table)

#Execute all queries
queries = [ create_database, create_table, query_1, query_2 ]
for q in queries:
   print("Executing query: %s" % (q))
   res = run_query(q, database, s3_ouput)
```

Comment: Take a look in your `~/.aws/config` file. Does it contain `import boto3` on line 7? If so, that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Yeah right, ~/.aws/config file had import boto3 which I've removed and executed the script, but now I am getting Executing query:                                                                 
 $ ./Athena_Script.py                                                    
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS s3_accesslog1;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Athena_Script.py", line 75, in <module>
    res = run_query(q, database, s3_ouput)
  File "./Athena_Script.py", line 10, in run_query
    'Database': s3_accesslog1
NameError: name 's3_accesslog1' is not defined

Comment: Please edit your question to show the current error output, rather than putting it in a (hard to read) comment. You can remove the error that you have now fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question and update the error.

Comment: It is saying that the IAM User you are using is not authorized to use Athena. In fact, it says that the permissions are explicitly denying access. It also mentions a workgroup called `primary`, so perhaps you can specify a different one in the command and it might work? Or, it might be on the User as a whole.

Comment: I've fixed the permission issue and now when I run the script the Database got created, but after that it is not able to create the Table. Please find the error which I get after executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the command is being run with:

```
QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': s3_accesslog1
            },
```

However, the database doesn't exist -- in fact, you are trying to create it!

So, try removing that entry and see whether it works. It means you will need to specify the database/schema in each query, but that is often a good idea to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks John, for the response. After removing the QueryExecutionContext I'm getting the error as updated above.

Comment: I normally see the `no viable alternative` error when my query has an error. To debug it, take the query that is displayed and run it manually in the Amazon Athena interface. I just did this, and it seems that **a table name cannot contain a hyphen**. Underscores can be used instead.